# Swift - How to define core data context in OS X

Tags: macos, swift, core-data

Thanks to online tutorials I have been using core data with swift and iOS.  To define a context I have used

```
let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```

How do I define the context when writing an OS X application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I define it that way:

```
lazy var context: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    let appDel = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    if let moc = appDel.managedObjectContext {
        return moc
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}()
```

Comment: Thank you that helped me tremendously!

Answer (score 0):

You could also have done:

```
let context = (NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```

- UIApplication has changed to NSApplication
- 'as!' changed to 'as'